# Copying variables, creating temporary variables and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I was learning about move semantics and rvalue references when I came across this web page  https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html. There is a piece of code that confuses me.

Without move semantics

```
template <class T> swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(a);   // now we have two copies of a
    a = b;      // now we have two copies of b
    b = tmp;    // now we have two copies of tmp (aka a)
}
```

With move semantics

```
template <class T> swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T tmp(std::move(a));
    a = std::move(b);   
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

How can we perform two copies of `a` `b` and `tmp`. Specially `a` and `b` since they are passed by reference.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. What is it that you are confused about? Also beware that the document you link is from 2006 when the first C++ revision including move semantics was finished only in 2011. There is a chance that what is written there may apply to the draft at the time but have had changes in the final C++ standard.

Comment: `// now we have two copies of a` refers to the copy just made and the original passed as a parameter to which the reference was attached.

Comment: @RichardCritten but a copy will also be made at the moment when we are executing `a=std::move(b);`. So we will have the local `a` with the value of `b` and a variable outside the function `swap` with the same value as `a` in the moment of executing `a=std::move(b);`. Therefore, you end up having two copies at that moment. Isn't it?

Comment: @SergioPrieto `a=std::move(b);` steals the contents of `b` (assuming it's a complex enough object) and moves its contents into `a` replacing what was in `a`.   After the assignment `b` has no useful content as they have been stolen and put into `a`. Only 1 copy of the internals of `b` ever exist 1st in `b` and then the contents in `a`.

Comment: Which code block are you questioning? You ask about "two copies", and I see "two copies" mentioned in the first code block, but that's the block without `std::move`. Yet, you say your question is about move semantics, which suggests your question should refer to the second code block. You probably should use more than one sentence to explain your confusion. Don't worry -- there is no additional charge for editing your question to add more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let a' and b' be the values in `a` and `b` before the function.

```
template <class T> swap(T& a, T& b)
{
  T tmp(a);   // now we have two copies of a' (in a and tmp) and one of b' (in b)
  a = b;      // now we have two copies of b' (in a and b) and one of a' (in tmp)
  b = tmp;    // now we have two copies of a' (in b and tmp) and one of b' (in a)
}
```

that might help.

Then we do the move version:

```
template <class T> swap(T& a, T& b)
{
  T tmp(std::move(a)); // a' is in tmp; b' is in b; a is moved-from
  a = std::move(b);    // a' is in tmp, b' is in a; b is moved-from
  b = std::move(tmp);  // a' is in b; b' is in a; tmp is moved-from
}
```

the trick is to distinguish between the *variable* `a` and the *value* stored in `a`.

Comment: But if we just erase the line ''b=std::move(tmp)'' then when returning to the main function we will have ''a'' with the value of ''b'' and ''b'' with the value of ''b''. So that is what is confusing me. You will end up with two copies.

Comment: @SergioPrieto b will not have the value of b. b's value will be indeterminate since its contents have been moved into a.

Comment: @SergioPrieto b will be moved-from.  What value that has depends on the semantics of the class `T`.  If it is something like a vector, it will be empty.  If it is something a std string, it will be in an unspecified state.  If it is something like an int, it will have the state it had last time it was written to (moving from an int doesn't change the int value).  In any case, "if you remove the last line it doesn't work" -- of course it doesn't work.  That is the point?

Comment: @SergioPrieto: After a move the original variable (the moved from) is "empty". Except for primitive types. But the details must be looked up for the specific Move Constructor and Move Assignment Operator of the classes in use. E.g., if in your example T is std::unique_ptr<int> the outer variable of b will be "empty" (points to nullptr) after a = std::move(b);